# ExtJs 3 portal with iframe

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I have an ExtJs portal/portlet component on my page, the contents of which is an iframe. When the portlet is dragged between portal positions (rearranged), some browsers reload the iframe (FF, Safari), and some don't (IE). Is there a way to prevent the reload from happening across all browsers?

```
new Ext.ux.Portlet( {
title : 'test',
id : 'test',
itemId : 'testId',
html : '<iframe src=testPage.html></iframe>' // testPage.html is reloaded when drop finishes
});
```

In Portal.js (v.3.3.0) there is this line of code which I am guessing is causing the iframe to reload:

```
 panel.el.dom.parentNode.removeChild(dd.panel.el.dom);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like, changing parent of iframe causes reload. So my idea is to attach iframe to some other parent, and position it over the portlet. Below is example portlet code.

```
{
    title: 'Another Panel 2',
    tools: tools,
    html: '<div class="frame-bind" style="min-height: 200px;">&nbsp;</div>',
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function(sender) {
            this.portal = this.findParentByType('portal');

            var container = this.portal.body;
            var html = '<iframe src="http://www.onet.pl" style="position: absolute; border: none;"></iframe>';
            this.iframe = Ext.DomHelper.append(container, html, true);

            this.portal.on('beforedragover', this.beforedragoverHandler, this);
            this.portal.on('drop', this.dropHandler, this);
        },
        destroy: function() {
            if (this.iframe !== undefined) {
                this.iframe.remove();
            }
            this.portal.un('beforedragover', this.beforedragoverHandler, this);
            this.portal.un('drop', this.dropHandler, this);
            delete this.portal;
        },
        afterlayout: function(sender, layout) {
            this.positionIframe.defer(1, this);
        }
    },
    beforedragoverHandler: function(sender) {
        if (this !== sender) { return; }
        this.iframe.setStyle('visibility', 'hidden');
    },
    dropHandler: function(sender) {
        if (this !== sender) { return; }
        this.positionIframe();
        this.iframe.setStyle('visibility', 'visible');
    },                  
    positionIframe: function() {
        this.iframe.setLocation(this.body.getLeft(), this.body.getTop());
        this.iframe.setWidth(this.body.getWidth());
        this.iframe.setHeight(this.body.getHeight());
    }
}
```

Comment: this is kind of working except some position calculation problem I can't solve. positionIFrame() will return 0's for new coordinates. afterLayout() calls it on drop complete for the last time, I'm assuming to get the most accurate coordinates, but doesn't quiet get coordinates right. Portals are wildly out of bonds. When i resize my browser (just nudge it), a recalculation of frame sizes occurs and that brings all the portals into their proper place again. Any ideas, from my description what it might be?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running a border layout? I had a similar issue on Ext 4 but I was able to solve via:

```
Ext.override(Ext.layout.container.Border, {
isValidParent: function() {
    return true;
}
});
```